# Resolving Duplicate Index Issues in Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm currently working on a data analysis project in Python, where I need to assign unique identifiers (UUIDs) to matched transactions in a Polars DataFrame. The DataFrame is being manipulated using the Polars library, and the logic includes assigning UUIDs to pairs of sales and return transactions based on certain conditions.

Here's a snippet of my code:

python

```
import uuid
import time
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
start_time = time.time()
from collections import defaultdict

number = 0

def assign_uuid_to_matched_transactions(transactions: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.LazyFrame:
    global number
    o = transactions.filter(pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "RETURN").select(pl.col("index").last()).to_series().to_list()

    if len(o) == 1:
        cleaned = transactions.filter(pl.col("index") <= o[0]).with_columns(pl.col("sold_item_quantity").abs().cast(pl.UInt64).alias("q"))
    else:
        return transactions


#     print(cleaned)
    
    repeats = (
        cleaned
        .select(
            pl.exclude('q').repeat_by('q').explode()
        )
        .with_columns(
            pl.lit(1).alias('quantity')
        ).with_row_count(name="temp_index")
    )
    
    returns = repeats.filter(
        (pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "RETURN")
    ).sort("temp_index").select(pl.col("index")).to_series().to_list()

    # Filter out the transactions of type "SALE" and collect their indices.
    sales = repeats.filter(
        pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "SALE"
    ).with_columns(
        pl.col("index").alias("sales_index")
    ).sort("temp_index").select(pl.col("index")).to_series().to_list()
    
    # Reverse the lists
    returns_reversed = returns[::-1]
    sales_reversed = sales[::-1]

    # Create a list of tuples
    index_pairs = list(zip(returns_reversed, sales_reversed))

   
    # Create a defaultdict with set as default factory
    grouped_items = defaultdict(set)

    # Group second items by the first item into a set, and add the key itself
    for first, second in index_pairs:
        grouped_items[first].add(second)
        grouped_items[first].add(first)


    for key, values in grouped_items.items():
        transaction_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())[:13]  # Generate a new UUID for each pair.
        # Filter transactions for the current pair (return and sale) and assign the generated UUID.
        transactions = transactions.with_columns(
            pl.when(
                (pl.col("index").is_in(list(values)))
                &(pl.col("uuid") == "")
            ).then(
                pl.col("uuid").str.replace("", transaction_uuid)
            ).otherwise(
                pl.col("uuid")
            )
        )
        

    return transactions
    
yyy = (
    xxx
    .group_by(["customer_id", "sold_item_id"])
    .map_groups(
        lambda customer_value_group: customer_value_group
        .set_sorted("sold_item_transaction_date_time")
        .rolling("sold_item_transaction_date_time", period="91d")
        .map_groups(
            lambda time_group: assign_uuid_to_matched_transactions(time_group)
            if (time_group.filter(
                (pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "RETURN") & 
                (pl.col("uuid") == "")
            ).shape[0] > 0 and
                time_group.filter(pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "SALE").shape[0] > 0)
            else time_group
            ,schema=None
        ),
        schema=None
    )
).collect(streaming=True)
```

[image]

The main dataframe is xxx and the altered one with duplicate index is yyy!
However, I'm encountering an issue where I end up with duplicate indexes in my DataFrame after running this code. This is causing problems in subsequent processing steps. I'm looking for insights on two fronts:

How can I modify my code to prevent or fix these duplicate indexes while still achieving the desired functionality?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

xxx as a dict. for reproducing the question:

```
'{"columns":[{"name":"index","datatype":"UInt32","bit_settings":"","values":[739919,739920,739921,739922,739923,739924,739925,739926,1528725,2077402,2077403,2077404,2077405,2077406,2085941,2085942,2085943,2085944,2085945,10799328,10799329,10799330,10799331,10799332,10799333,10800017,10800018,10800019,11091316,11091317,11091318,11091319,11091320,11132760,11166939,11166940,11181336,11181337,12058438,12439881,26199468,26199469,26289443,26289444,26289445,26830410,26830411,26830412,53686703,53686704,53686705,53702140,53702141,53734505,55566465,55566466,67303703,67303704,67303705,67303706,67303709,67303710,67303711,71919755,71919756,72188080,72188081,72188082,72188083,72188084,72188085,72693658,72693659]},{"name":"customer_id","datatype":"UInt64","bit_settings":"","values":[1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478,1870478]},{"name":"transaction_id","datatype":"UInt64","bit_settings":"","values":[4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756772069089738752,4756775871766331392,4756778558717165568,4756778558717165568,4756778558717165568,4756778558717165568,4756778558717165568,4756778584024547328,4756778584024547328,4756778584024547328,4756778584024547328,4756778584024547328,4756814255580774400,4756814255580774400,4756814255580774400,4756814255580774400,4756814255580774400,4756814255580774400,4756814282843226112,4756814282843226112,4756814282843226112,4756815747626303488,4756815747626303488,4756815747626303488,4756815747626303488,4756815747626303488,4756815933191749632,4756816036430348288,4756816036430348288,4756816183199006720,4756816183199006720,4756820277378678784,4756822137022971904,4756874320996728832,4756874320996728832,4756874755623092224,4756874755623092224,4756874755623092224,4756877098866966528,4756877098866966528,4756877098866966528,4756979475879559168,4756979475879559168,4756979475879559168,4756979519361908736,4756979519361908736,4756979598131986432,4756986314688036864,4756986314688036864,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757015231786385408,4757025994326409216,4757025994326409216,4757026690181365760,4757026690181365760,4757026690181365760,4757026690181365760,4757026690181365760,4757026690181365760,4757028024428789760,4757028024428789760]},{"name":"sold_item_transaction_type","datatype":"Utf8","bit_settings":"","values":["SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","RETURN","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","RETURN","RETURN","RETURN","RETURN","RETURN","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","RETURN","RETURN","RETURN","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","RETURN","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","SALE","RETURN","RETURN"]},{"name":"sold_item_final_value","datatype":"Float64","bit_settings":"","values":[5.0,0.0,21.0,5.0,3.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,-21.0,5.0,9.0,19.0,5.0,7.0,-5.0,-9.0,-19.0,-5.0,-7.0,11.0,7.0,7.0,4.0,5.0,0.0,11.0,7.0,6.0,23.0,47.0,20.0,32.0,0.0,47.0,26.0,0.0,35.0,7.0,65.0,0.0,9.0,0.0,35.0,42.0,47.0,-42.0,-47.0,-35.0,9.0,7.0,0.0,38.0,0.0,-7.0,41.0,0.0,23.4,0.0,5.4,50.4,36.0,39.6,50.4,39.9,0.0,10.0,17.0,14.0,20.0,20.0,0.0,-20.0,-14.0]},{"name":"sold_item_quantity","datatype":"Float64","bit_settings":"","values":[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,1.0,-6.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0]},{"name":"sold_item_transaction_date_time","datatype":{"Datetime":["Microseconds",null]},"bit_settings":"","values":[1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1610564649000000,1611694660000000,1612463318000000,1612463318000000,1612463318000000,1612463318000000,1612463318000000,1612469153000000,1612469153000000,1612469153000000,1612469153000000,1612469153000000,1623428698000000,1623428698000000,1623428698000000,1623428698000000,1623428698000000,1623428698000000,1623428729000000,1623428729000000,1623428729000000,1623773542000000,1623773542000000,1623773542000000,1623773542000000,1623773542000000,1623838041000000,1623858557000000,1623858557000000,1623865275000000,1623865275000000,1625153394000000,1625689218000000,1641331346000000,1641331346000000,1641479802000000,1641479802000000,1641479802000000,1642194420000000,1642194420000000,1642194420000000,1674046417000000,1674046417000000,1674046417000000,1674056190000000,1674056190000000,1674077957000000,1676558992000000,1676558992000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1692114265000000,1697547175000000,1697547175000000,1697846798000000,1697846798000000,1697846798000000,1697846798000000,1697846798000000,1697846798000000,1698610913000000,1698610913000000]},{"name":"sold_item_id","datatype":"Utf8","bit_settings":"","values":["148845068","112132996","143868444","148213089","148845099","148845099","148845068","148685565","143868444","148827408","148691528","147654920","148213089","148213225","148827408","148691528","147654920","148213089","148213225","151722950","150800505","150833701","151065880","151723193","130169660","153042841","150799120","150799946","150676872","147742696","104775903","152527042","130169660","149372105","131843897","130169660","150637316","148840506","152051332","130169660","153297012","130169660","152084804","152084958","152084811","152084958","152084811","152084804","159577484","153572003","112132996","152083807","112132996","153572003","158639039","130169660","159666010","130169660","140230176","161734981","161602150","162575262","161733533","163431901","130169660","151063831","157587775","160356320","163431703","157587805","130169660","163431703","160356320"]},{"name":"uuid","datatype":"Utf8","bit_settings":"SORTED_ASC","values":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]}]}'
```

Comment: What does 'xxx' means?

Comment: it's my source dataframe I'm gonna do something on it.  The out put of it has been brought in the picture.  Sorry for improper naming though!

Comment: It's difficult or impossible to help you without a MWE of the problem that can be replicated.

Comment: Although perhaps the actual question should be *"How do I write this using Polars Expressions?"* because it looks this could all be done using a single `.rolling(index_column=""sold_item_transaction_date_time", by=["customer_id", "sold_item_id"], period="91d").agg()` call.

Comment: @jqurious  I tested the .rolling method you mentioned, but it gave me a different output. It starts by rolling the time and then groups by the columns. However, I need it to first create groups based on the columns and then roll within each group."

Comment: In more general terms, doing this "natively" in Polars would mean getting rid of all `.map_groups()` calls and instead using `.agg()` where applicable. (Will try to take a closer look at your example to fully understand what you need to do.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to answer the question in its current state, but this too long to put in a comment:

There is quite a lot going on here which makes it difficult to debug.

The first step would be to implement the functionality without using
[`.map_groups()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.map_groups.html#polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.map_groups)

> **Warning:** This method is much slower than the native expressions API. Only use it if you cannot implement your logic otherwise.

From what I can tell, It looks there are 3 pieces of logic to test for a valid transaction group:

- at least 1 `RETURN` with `uuid = ""`
- at least 1 `SALE`
- only 1 `RETURN`

As an example, that could look something like:

```py
return_transaction_with_empty_uuid = (
   (pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "RETURN") & (pl.col("uuid") == "")
)

sale_transaction = pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "SALE"

return_transaction_count = (pl.col("sold_item_transaction_type") == "RETURN").sum()

has_a_transaction_match = (
   return_transaction_with_empty_uuid.any() & 
   sale_transaction.any() & 
   return_transaction_count == 1
)

(df.group_by("customer_id", "sold_item_id")
   .agg(match = has_a_transaction_match)
   .head(8)
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬───────┐
│ customer_id ┆ sold_item_id ┆ match │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---   │
│ u64         ┆ str          ┆ bool  │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1870478     ┆ 148845099    ┆ false │
│ 1870478     ┆ 148685565    ┆ false │
│ 1870478     ┆ 148840506    ┆ false │
│ 1870478     ┆ 152084804    ┆ true  │
│ 1870478     ┆ 158639039    ┆ false │
│ 1870478     ┆ 148213089    ┆ true  │
│ 1870478     ┆ 148213225    ┆ true  │
│ 1870478     ┆ 104775903    ┆ false │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴───────┘
```

It could be used inside `.agg(pl.when(...))` to conditionally process the groups.

But `assign_uuid_to_matched_transactions` is much more complex, and there is the added `.rolling()` component.

Perhaps a reduced example that focuses on just a single "group" of data that explains/shows what exactly is going on here could be created. (Maybe as a new question?)

That may make it easier for people to suggest how to do it "natively" with Polars.